# ComboBox in CellEditingTemplate

Tags: wpf, vb.net, combobox, celleditingtemplate

I am trying to use a ComboBox in a DataGrid CellEditingTemplate, binding to an existing DataTable. When I double click the item, the ComboBox displays, but there is no data in it. I've researched different options for a couple of days, but nothing seems to work.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header=" Venue" CanUserSort="False">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Venue}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=dtVenues, ElementName=MyWindow}"
                       DisplayMemberPath="Venue" 
                       SelectedValuePath="Venue"
                       Text="{Binding Venue}"/> 
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The DataTable dtVenues is declared as Public in code behind (VB). Can anyone please point me in the right direction for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you've declared the `dtVenues` collection for your `ComboBox`es in the code behind of your `Window` and set the `Window.DataContext` property value to the code behind class in one way or another. If that is true, then I believe that you need to change your `Binding` slightly to address the `Window.DataContext`:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.dtVenues, ElementName=MyWindow}"... />
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. dtVenues is part of a DataSet and is declared and populated in MainWindow. The XAML is also for the MainWindow. Do I still need to set a DataContext?

Comment: `DataContext` in the `Binding.Path` above relates to whatever object you set as the `DataContext` of your `Window`. If you set that to itself (`MainWindow.xaml`), then you will need to use it in the `Path`. And yes, you *always* need to set the `DataContext` using one method or another, or the UI will have no... data context... no data.